# spring kafka, how to gracefully shutdown the spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am having Kafka Consumers in a Spring Boot application. I have kept ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG as false and my consumers are manually acknowledging the messages.
Spring-Kafka: 2.2.11.RELEASE

My configuration:

```
 @Override
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, heartbeatInterval);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMs);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryServers);

    return props;
  }
```

Connection Factory

```
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V> kvConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    kvConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, getAvroKeyDeserializer(),
                                             getAvroValueDeserializer());
    kvConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()
                                             .setAckOnError(false);
    kvConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()
                                             .setAckMode(
                                                 ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

Kafka Consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic-name}", groupId = "${group-id}", containerFactory = CONTAINER_FACTORY)
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<Key, Envelope> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    final Envelope envelope = record.value();
    if(//some condition){
         //logic
    }
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
  }
```

**The issue** is offset is lost if the application crashes at If statement.

**My understanding** is if 'acknowledgment.acknowledge();' is not done and application crashes then on restart the same message should be processed again.

I need help to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean by "application crashes"? If the JVM is shut down, the record will be redelivered. If you mean an exception is thrown and you are using a version older than 2.5.x (Boot 2.3), you can configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` so, if the listener throws an exception, the record will be redelivered. With 2.5, that's the default error handler. With earlier versions, the error would be logged and the consumer moves on.

Comment: @GaryRussell Huge respect for you :) I am using spring-kafka 2.2.11 RELEASE. I am testing out things in local and for this scenario, I have put a debug point at If statement, and when control comes there I am forcefully shutdown the JVM. On the restart, I am expecting the same message as offset was not committed.

Comment: Given that scenario, you should see the record redelivered because the offset will not be committed until you call `acknowledge()`. If that's not what you are seeing, something else is going on.